# Removing and replacing multiple synonym words and phrases (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

As the title suggests I want to replace all synonyms (words and phrases) with a specific synonym to clean some text based data. For example if I have the following (inane) sentence :

*"my doggo hates cattos, as a golden retriever he finds felines unnerving"*

I would want to replace all dog related words with the word dog and all cat related words with the word cat. So the sentence becomes the following

*my dog hates cats, as a dog he finds cats unnerving"*

Assuming doggo and golden retriever are 'dog' words and catto and feline are 'cat' words.

I was hoping to build some form of dictionary / key, value mapping object a bit like this:

```
obj = {'dog':['doggo'||'doggy'||'golden\Sretriever']}
```

However I can't seem to make it work with multiple values assigned to a single key.

Comment: `obj = {'dog':['doggo','doggy','golden retriever']};`...

Comment: Why not store regexp literals directly to the object? Like `obj = {dog: /[doggo|doggy| ...]/};`

Comment: Rather, `{dog: /\b(doggo|doggy)\b/g,....}` and then `Object.keys.forEach(text = text.replace(obj[k], k)`

Comment: @Teemu Good idea, but certainly you don't mean to put them in a `[]` character set.

Comment: @torazaburo Ah, I forgot to remove the brackets from the copy-paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to iterate through all the keys in your dictionary and create a regex for that specific key. Then you just feed that regex to the **.replace()** with the **synonym regex** and the key you want to replace it with.

```js
let sentence = "my doggo hates cattos, as a golden retriever he finds felines unnerving";

const synonyms = {
  "dog": ['doggo','doggy', 'golden retriever'],
  "cat": ['catto', 'feline']
};

function fileAndReplace(sentence, synonyms) {
  let newSentence = sentence;
    
  Object.keys(synonyms).forEach(key => {
      const checkSynonyms = new RegExp(synonyms[key].join('|'),'gi');
      newSentence = newSentence.replace(checkSynonyms, key);
  })
     
  return newSentence;
}

console.log(fileAndReplace(sentence, synonyms))
```

You could even go a little further and create a second **data structure** with pre-computed **synonym regex**, this way you avoid computing it for each sentence/text/doc and reduce the computation within the loop to a look up and search.

This might improve the performance. But then again that might be a little out of this questions scope.

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted - this does exactly what I needed it to do. Its very similar to a solution I had started to work down but actually works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use RegExp and join

```
var dogs = {'dog':['doggo','doggy','golden retriever']};
var sentence = "my doggo hates cattos, as a golden retriever he finds felines unnerving";
sentence.replace(new RegExp(dogs.dog.join("|"), "gmi"), "dog");
// "my dog hates cattos, as a dog he finds felines unnerving"
```

Comment: Thanks - this came close to what I was after but Jordans solution was more complete as it allowed everything to be contained in one method rather than having to do a separate replace for each entity i.e. one for cats and one for dogs. Thank you for you help.